# Finding seasonal satellite map tiles?

Tags: data, cartography, tiles, satellite

I am working on an exhibit/geospatial visualization which shows the migration of marine animals over time throughout the year. I am searching for seasonal satellite map tiles. Does anyone know of any?

For now I am using Mapbox's satellite tiles.

Comment: There are month-by-month images in http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/BlueMarble/ - does that have enough resolution for what you need? You can view them at http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484

Comment: Those are perfect, almost! I am wondering if there is a WMS that hosts them. I know that opengeo.org hosts a non-seasonal version of blue marble.

Comment: I don't know of any off hand. You could set one up, or it may be on one of the NASA WMS servers.